# 3 Questions concerning the fundamental group of $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have the following questions:

1) What is the fundamental group of $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^1$ and why?

2) Is $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^1$ homeomorphic to the bouquet of 3 circles

3) Are $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^1$ and the bouquet of 3 circles homotopic to one another?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 2, 3) I'd say it *is* the bouquet of 3 circles. (If the bouquet of 3 circles is not *defined* to be $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$, what is its definition?) 1) Apply Van Kampen twice - once to get the fundamental group of $S^1 \vee S^1$ and once more for $(S^1 \vee S^1) \vee S^1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I always thought that the bouquet of 3 circles coincides with a rose with three petals, but $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^1$ can be thought as three circles, that are glued together, but that there are 2 gluing ponits...is that not correct?

Comment: They're glued together at the same point.

Comment: If you interpret $X=(S^1\vee S^1)\vee S^1$ to be glued on two *different* points, the result is *not homeomorphic* to the bouquet of $3$ circles since you have $2$ points where $X$ is not locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, but only $1$ such point in the bouquet. They are still *homotopy equivalent* though, if $A$ is one of the arcs connecting the $2$ gluing points, $X\to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence and $X/A$ is homeomorphic to the bouquet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The fundamental group of $S^1\lor S^1\lor S^1$ is a free group on three generators: each generator is the homotopy class of a loop about one of the three circles. More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are path-connected spaces with fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ and $\pi_1(Y)$ then the fundamental group $\pi_1(X\lor Y)$ is isomorphic to the [free product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product) of $\pi_1(X)$ and $\pi_1(Y)$. This follows from the [Seifert-van Kampen Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Kampen%27s_theorem).
2. $S^1\lor S^1\lor S^1$ is homeomorphic to the bouquet of $3$ circles -- in fact, it is usually taken as the *definition* of that bouquet.